# Activity not showing all the fragments

Tags: android

I have a Activity with 4 fragments. Each fragment consists of a listView. The bottom Fragments are not shown when the above fragments has data that fills up the screen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your Activity's root layout.
Your top fragment's heigh is probably match_parent.
Divide the layout on the parts you need (use layout_weight for example or height in dp) and make one below another.